# Restrict access to certain route values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I prevent the user from accessing a certail url for example /Edit/4?
The id 4 does not belong to him so I want to show an unauthorized page instead.

I have a userId field in db I can check if the id in the url is ok to show.

I have tried a custom authorizeattribute but I dont know how to access the parameter sent to the actionresult.

```
public class EditOwnAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // Custom property
    public string Level { get; set; }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }




        return false;
    }
```

Comment: post a code or your maybe we can help you!

Comment: How do you know that ID 4 in your example doesn't belong to user. Do you have a table with it or some code? Do you mean that user may edit only his posts?

Comment: since you know the id 4 does not belong to him, it means you have it somewhere in the database. in the Edit action, why dont you check the id and userid and if an id does not belong to a user, send him to an error page...wouldn't that be the easiest soln.

Comment: Yes I mean that users may edit only his posts.

Comment: Yes I can implement in all actions but it will be a lot of dry code everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to restrict access with custom Authorization filter like below

```
    [FeatureAuthentication(AllowFeature="OverView")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }
```

Then

```
public class FeatureAuthenticationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public FeatureConst AllowFeature { get; set; }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //var featureConst = (FeatureConst)filterContext.RouteData.Values["AllowFeature"];

        var filterAttribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterAttributes(true)
                                .Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(FeatureAuthenticationAttribute));
        if (filterAttribute != null)
        {
            foreach (FeatureAuthenticationAttribute attr in filterAttribute)
            {
                AllowFeature = attr.AllowFeature;
            }

            User currentLoggedInUser = (User)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentUser"];
            bool allowed = ACLAccessHelper.IsAccessible(AllowFeature.ToString(), currentLoggedInUser);
            // do your logic...
            if (!allowed)
            {
                string unAuthorizedUrl = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext).RouteUrl(new { controller = "home", action = "UnAuthorized" });
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(unAuthorizedUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```